# How can I maintain access to applications when converting an Azure user from 'Member' to 'Guest'?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We currently have a number of users in Azure AD with the account type "member" that we are converting to account type "guest" as part of a Azure B2B initiative. These users were originally replicated from our on-prem AD environment and are accessing applications based on on-prem AD groups. Whenever we convert these users from "member" to "guest," will they lose access to all groups? If so, does anyone have a way either via script or using an Azure tool to make sure they're access doesn't disappear?

I've searched through the documentation and only found information on converting "member" to "guest," but not the other way around.

This is not a coding related question

Comment: Have you tried converting a user to a guest? This operation should not change group memberships as it only changes the user's type.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the exact steps you plan to follow to change the user from member to guest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the *UserType* attribute of the existing User object is changed from "Member" to "Guest" (and the object ID stays the same), existing access grants, app assignment, and group memberships will still be valid. (Though not all applications will necessarily continue to work like they did before, as the guest user will have limited permissions some services.)

If you *replace* the User object with a new one (different object ID), all the previous access grants and app assignments will be lost.

Comment: Okay cool! I haven't gotten around to testing yet, but just wanted to set an expected result. Thank you very much!